# Using Android ProcessBuilder from network location

Tags: android, processbuilder

My situation is that I have over 100 android devices to update which are not connected to the internet but a local network. What I am tring to do is use the process builder to access an apk on the local network and install the apk without user intervention.

The devices are currently not rooted, however as I will have to pull them all in for this update anyway they can all be rooted if needs be.

Currently I am just running from the onCreate process of a new app, when I get the code working I will just have the app as a background service that peridiocally checks the network for a new file.

This is what I have tried, but am getting an IO error and then a list of on device locations that the device has looking in for the file.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("su","-c", "'pm install -r http://192.168.0.17:8080/updateTest/my.apk'");
        try {
                Process shell = pb.start();
                InputStream shellIn = shell.getInputStream();
                String response = IOUtils.toString(shellIn, "UTF-8");
                Log.w("myApp.update", response);
                shellIn.close();
                shell.destroy();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.w("myApp.update", "failed" + ex);
        }



    }      
}
```

and the logcat message:

```
06-26 17:00:37.886: E/myApp.update(11072): failedjava.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [su, -c, 'pm install -r http://192.168.0.17:8080/updateTest/myapp.apk'] Working Directory: null Environment: [ANDROID_SOCKET_zygote=9, SECONDARY_STORAGE=/storage/extSdCard:/storage/UsbDriveA:/storage/UsbDriveB:/storage/UsbDriveC:/storage/UsbDriveD:/storage/UsbDriveE:/storage/UsbDriveF, OMX_STE_ENS_COMPONENTS_DIR=/system/lib/ste_omxcomponents/, OMX_BELLAGIO_LOADER_REGISTRY=/system/omxloaders, ANDROID_BOOTLOGO=1, EXTERNAL_STORAGE=/storage/sdcard0, ANDROID_ASSETS=/system/app, ASEC_MOUNTPOINT=/mnt/asec, PATH=/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin:/sbin:/bin:/vendor/bin, LOOP_MOUNTPOINT=/mnt/obb, BOOTCLASSPATH=/system/framework/core.jar:/system/framework/core-junit.jar:/system/framework/bouncycastle.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/framework2.jar:/system/framework/android.policy.jar:/system/framework/services.jar:/system/framework/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/sec_edm.jar:/system/framework/seccamera.jar, ANDROID_DATA=/data, ANDROID_ROOT=/system, LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/system/lib:/lib:/usr/lib:/system/lib/ste_omxcomponents/:/vendor/lib, ANDROID_PROPERTY_WORKSPACE=8,66560]
```

So has anyone got any ideas or experience in this?

UPDATE

Ok so now I am grabbing the file first and then trying to install using the code below:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private long enqueue;
    private DownloadManager dm;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
                    long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(
                            DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
                    Query query = new Query();
                    query.setFilterById(enqueue);
                    Cursor c = dm.query(query);
                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        int columnIndex = c
                                .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                        if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c
                                .getInt(columnIndex)) {

                            //ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                            String uriString = c
                                    .getString(c
                                            .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));
                           // view.setImageURI(Uri.parse(uriString));

                          installapk();


                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            private void installapk() {
                 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("su","-c", "pm install -r " + Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/sr.apk");
                    try {
                            Process shell = pb.start();
                            InputStream shellIn = shell.getInputStream();
                            String response = IOUtils.toString(shellIn, "UTF-8");
                            Log.e("myApp.update", response);
                            shellIn.close();
                            shell.destroy();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {

                            Log.e("myApp.update", "failed" + ex);
                    }
            }
        };

        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(
                DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));

        onClick();
    }

    public void onClick() {


      dm = (DownloadManager) this.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        DownloadManager.Request req = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse("http://192.168.0.62:12345/sr.apk"));
        req.setTitle("sr.apk")
                        .setDescription("Downloading ....")
                        // download the package to the /sdcard/downlaod path.
                        .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "sr.apk");
           enqueue = dm.enqueue(req);

    }



}
```

However I am still getting the same error! The device is rooted and my permissions are as follows:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Anyone got anymore ideas?!

Update 2!

Ok, well double checked and turns out the phone wasn't rooted! Now rooted and tried again adding the requires super user permission in my manifest, now the code below runs to completion without error, however nothing is installed and 'response' is empty?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private long enqueue;
    private DownloadManager dm;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
                    Query query = new Query();
                    query.setFilterById(enqueue);
                    Cursor c = dm.query(query);
                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        int columnIndex = c
                                .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                        if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c.getInt(columnIndex)) 
                        {
                          installapk();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            private void installapk() {

                    try {
                            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("su","-c", "install -r " +Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/sr.apk");
                            Process shell = pb.start();
                            pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
                            InputStream shellIn = shell.getInputStream();
                            String response = IOUtils.toString(shellIn, "UTF-8");
                            Log.e("myApp.update", response);
                            shellIn.close();
                            shell.destroy();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {

                            Log.e("myApp.update", "failed" + ex);
                    }
            }
        };

        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(
                DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));

        onClick();
    }

    public void onClick() {


      dm = (DownloadManager) this.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        DownloadManager.Request req = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse("http://192.168.0.62:12345/sr.apk"));
        req.setTitle("sr.apk").setDescription("Downloading ....").setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "sr.apk");
           enqueue = dm.enqueue(req);

    }
}
```

Anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what directory are you trying to execute in? did you try setting the directory with `pb.directory("/home");` ?

Comment: good point! I guess I would need to grab the file from the server 1st and then try to install it, bit of a logic fail on my part

Comment: "install the apk without user intervention" -- that's not possible without superuser access

Comment: Thats fine, I can root the device if thats what you mean

Comment: question updated with latest attempts!